# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'time'

Tags: python, datetime

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'time'
```

SO i want this list of list timeList = [ [ ],[ ],[ ] ] to store my firstTime,
secondtime and thirdTime
but it throws me an error. any idea on this

```
from datetime import datetime, date,timedelta

timeList = [[],[],[]]
timeList[1].append(datetime.now())
secondTime=timeList[1].time() # throws an error 
print(secondTime)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `timeList` is a list of lists, hence every item in it is from type `list`.

When your run:

```py
secondTime=timeList[1].time()
```

You are accessing the second item of `timeList`, which is a list itself, and trying to call `time`.

Try the following line instead:

```py
secondTime=timeList[1][0].time()
```

Answer (score 1):

You want this:

```
>>> secondTime = timeList[1][0].time() 
>>>
>>> timeList
[[], [datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 2, 17, 38, 12, 274423)], []]
>>> 
>>> timeList[1]
[datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 2, 17, 38, 12, 274423)]
>>> 
>>> secondTime
datetime.time(17, 38, 12, 274423)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to give the location of the item by saying where in the list you want to find it, and then look inside that sub-list. this works:

```
from datetime import datetime, date,timedelta
timeList = [[],[],[]]
timeList[1].append(datetime.now())
secondTime=timeList[1][0].time() # throws an error 
print(secondTime)
```